# Multiple IF Statements Not working with each other

Tags: c#, debugging

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class MainClass
    {
        // Entry Point For Program
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");

            String Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Thank you, so your name is {Name}?:");
            if (Console.ReadLine() == "Yes" || Console.ReadLine() == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"So I will be calling you {Name}");
            }
            
            if(Console.ReadLine() == "No" || Console.ReadLine() == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Then Enter your Name again:");
                String Name2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"So your name this time is {Name}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I want to be able to type in either Yes/yes or No/no but it only detects the Yes/yes first so I have to say Yes/yes and I can't say No/no

Comment: Each time you call ReadLine you will read another line

Comment: Assign a single call to `ReadLine` to a variable and then check that.

Comment: @juharr I'm new to coding so I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean instead of calling it string Name 2 just overwrite the other string name?

Comment: Do `var answer = Console.ReadLine();` and then `if(answer  == "Yes" || answer == "yes")` and `if(answer == "No" || answer == "no")`

Comment: Do i just delete this post or can i flag that it was fixed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to call ReadLine once

```
        Console.WriteLine($"Thank you, so your name is {Name}?:");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response == "Yes" || response == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"So I will be calling you {Name}");
        }
```

or even

```
        Console.WriteLine($"Thank you, so your name is {Name}?:");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response.ToLower() == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"So I will be calling you {Name}");
        }
```